# placeing bitmaps in live wallpapers

Tags: android, canvas, live-wallpaper

Hello I am trying to place acouple bitmaps on the screen and rotate them. I can get this to work by doing

```
canvas.drawBitmap(pic2, rotatePic, null);
```

`rotatePic` is matrix with

```
postRotate(5, pic2.getHieght()/2, pic2.getWidth()/2)
```

this rotates the pic and puts it at `0, 0` so to place it i tried

```
Bitmap topPic = Bitmap.createBitmap(pic2, 0, 0, pic2.getWidth(), 
        pic2.getHeight(), rotatePic, false);
```

than place with

```
canvas.drawBitmap(topPic, 200, 100, null);
```

it places it correctley but it no longer rotates correctley it looks like it is bouncing and spinning I've tried everthing

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively try rotating the canvas itself, using

```
canvas.rotate(degress, px, py);
```

Here's a link to the Android reference page for this:

[Canvas.rotate();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @joe : I understand my reply was very late, but it'd be useful to all if you could share how you solved this problem.. :)